# Jquery UI Menu Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-table

I have been working on a small application for the last little while. I am by no means a pro at this. I would like to have a jQuery UI Menu show up where the user clicks on my table. The problem is that the menu never shows up "over" the table but underneath (below as in farther down the page not under the table) it instead.

```
$("table.selectTable").delegate("tr", "click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    lastClicked = $(this);
    var menu = '#' + $(this).parent().parent().attr('name') + 'Menu';
    console.log(menu); //getting the result (the show and hide work as well)
    $(menu).hide();
    if (!event.shiftKey) {

        if ($(this).children().hasClass("highlight")) {
            console.log('event coords' + event.pageX + "," + event.pageY);
            console.log($(this).offset());
            //$(this).children().removeClass("highlight");

            position = $(this).position();
            if ($(menu).css('display') === 'none') {
                $(menu).menu().position({
                    my: "right top",
                    of: event
                });

                $(menu).show();
            } else {
                console.log('no menu to show');
                $(this).children().removeClass("highlight");
            }

        } else {
            console.log('add');
            $(this).parent().children().children().removeClass("highlight");
            $(this).children().addClass("highlight");
        }
    } else {
        if ($(this).children().hasClass("highlight")) {
            $(this).children().removeClass("highlight");
        } else {
            $(this).children().addClass("highlight");
        }
    }

    clearSelection();
});
```

This chunk of code which is ugly and no longer in use DOES work:
(was too specific, not terribly reusable, and depended on ugly checkboxes for selection - the highlighting was just to show which row the menu related to)

```
$("#groupList tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function(event) {
    lastClicked = $(this).children("td").next().html();
    $(this).parent().children().children().removeClass("highlight");
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.target.nodeName !== "INPUT" && $(event.target).children("input").first().attr('rel') === undefined) {
        $(this).children().addClass("highlight");
        $("#gListMenu").menu().position({
            my: "right top",
            of: event
        });
        $("#gListMenu").show();
    } else {
        $("#gListMenu").hide();
    }

});
```

I sincerely appreciate any input anyone has to offer as I've researched as much as I can.

Comment: Have you tried applying a z-index? If you can supply the HTML as well then I could construct a jsfiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately this project is using node.js, express, and .jade templates. I can send you the resulting html but its ugly and huge! Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Sorry, if it's huge I probably won't have time.  I started this fiddle for you, it's using a jQuery UI menu: **http://jsfiddle.net/Pnb2T/** Replace it with your code.  Then when you have it running, try altering the css by applying a `z-index` to get it to stay on top. Hope that helps.

Comment: Found it! You can't use .position() on elements which are hidden, you must .show() the menu (or element) first. Can't answer my own question, so have it at! [Thanks again, Gordon!]

Comment: As you say, you're right. You can't position an element that is hidden. However, if the element's position does not effect any other elements on the page, you can simply set it's css visibility `element.css({ visibility: 'hidden' })` and then manipulate it's .position. Hope this helps.